# What is the best way to write Feynman slash notation in MS word?

Tags: microsoft-word, unicode, latex, equation-editor

Writing slashes appear displaced usually in word.
What is the best way and most visually appealing to write a slash and how to adjust the position of the slash.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman_slash_notation

symbol combined with unicode 0338 gives something unpredictable

Ctrl F9 and inserting a field 'eq \o (here,/)',  can work also unpredictably but I cannot adjust its advanced features.

Answer (score 3):

I don’t understand the advanced features of the EQ field, either,
but one simple trick that’s not obvious is
that you can apply font formatting to the components of an overstrike. 
For example,

[image: EQ field with font formatting]

This is a screenshot of Microsoft Word 2013, taken at 500% zoom. 
What you see here is shrunken by Stack Exchange;
click on the image to see it full size.

A more flexible way to do overstrikes is with the ADVANCE field. 
It represents motion, and can be followed by a combination of
`\U num`, `\D num`,
`\L num`, and `\R num`,
to move up, down, left and/or right the indicated number of points. 
(Numbers, alas, must be integers. 
Spaces are optional in the parameter string;
e.g., `\L5\D1` is equivalent to `\ L 5 \ D 1`. 
All letters are case-insensitive.) 
For example,

[image: ADVANCE field (with font formatting)]

This is a screenshot taken at 450% zoom.

Now it’s up to you to pick the formatting that you want.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up here searching for the same doubt and after trying what you said about typing { EQ \O(a,/)} it didnt work (at least in my word version). After more internet researchs, I realized that in fact it should be written as { EQ \O(a;/)}, exactly the same its said in the previous comment, but using ";" instead of ",".

This worked for me, so I hope it can help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

To Type any letter with slash through it in Word, follow the instruction below:

Press Ctrl+F9
You will see {}
press eq \o (a,/) 
press Shift+F9

note: you should insert space after "q", after "o", and after ")" , that is you will see {eq \o (a,/) }

The example above is for typing the letter "a" with slash through it. To type any other letter with slash through it, type that letter in the same position as "a". This works for any letter.