# How to write Feynman slash notation in Microsoft Word?

Tags: microsoft-word

Feynman slash notation is when you put a dash on symbols, please have a look at:

[image]

how can this be done in Microsoft word?

Comment: It would appear not. The complete list of possibilities can be found at http://www.iun.edu/~mathiho/useful/Equation%20Editor%20Shortcut%20Commands.pdf

Comment: With LaTeX, it's easier: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/26525/1045

Answer (score 1):

I would expect that this would be possible using LaTeX - though, as I don't use it, I can't say for sure. Hopefully someone will correct me in the comments if it isn't possible.

You haven't said what version of Word you are using but since at least the [middle of last year](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/murrays/2017/07/30/latex-math-in-office/), if you are using the Office 365 version of Word, you've been able to use LaTeX anywhere that accepts math input.

---

There may be another option, as indicated in [this support post](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_other-mso_2010/want-to-write-using-the-equation-tool-with-feynman/8d498a8a-0225-471c-9a5d-aacb6670b0eb):

> Unicode character &h0338 is the "combining long solidus overlay".
>   Typing/inserting it after any character will overlay that character
>   with the slash. I've set up a math AutoCorrect on my computer to do it
>   when I type \slash.

Alternatively, [this SU post](https://superuser.com/questions/1150836/what-is-the-best-way-to-write-feynman-slash-notation-in-ms-word/1154164) gives another possibilty using the EQ field in Word.

---

You can also vote for more direct support [here](https://word.uservoice.com/forums/304924-word-for-windows-desktop-application/suggestions/19800316-feynman-slash-notation).

---

And there is some discussion of its use in TEX in this SE post:

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26523/whats-the-most-elegant-way-to-obtain-dirac-operators-slash-notation

Hopefully at least one of these will help.